# What is difference between se01, se09 and se10?

Tags: sap-basis

Please explain why there are different transaction codes (`se01`, `se09` and `se10`) for transporting handling in an ABAP-based system. What are the differences?

Answer (score 6):

In earlier SAP releases, *SE09* and *SE10* used to cover different areas:

- *SE09* was used for workbench/development transports
- *SE10* was used for customizing  transports

Nowadays, both transactions are the same (they use the same report internally).

Additionally, *SE01* is an extended transaction that combines SE09 and SE10 features, but adds a lot of additional ones such as displaying specific transport requests without knowing the assigned user names or searching based on clients.